# Outputting images and captions into bootstrap carousel using wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use wordpress to add images to my bootstrap carousel, I have attempted a foreach loop and then try to output each part of the array i want into the correct parts of the carousel however it doesn't seem to work.

Here is the code i'm using

```
<?php

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'orderby' => 'menu_order',
'order' => ASC,
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_status' => null,
'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'exclude' => get_post_thumbnail_id()
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);

$imageURL = array();


?>  
<!-- Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row carousel-row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Indicators -->
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>

                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner"> 
                        <?php $i=0; foreach ($attachments as $imageURL) { ?> 
                        '<div class="item <?php if ($i == 0) { echo 'active'; } ?>" style="background-size:cover; background:url('<?php echo $imageURL[guid]; ?>') no-repeat center;">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h4><?php echo $imageURL[post_excerpt];?></h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php $i++; } ?>
                    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On this line you have an extra apostrophe at the beginning:

```
'<div class="item <?php if ($i == 0)
```

It should read:

```
<div class="item <?php if ($i == 0)
```

To make:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <?php $i=0; foreach ($attachments as $imageURL) { ?>
  <div class="item <?php if ($i == 0) { echo 'active'; } ?>" style="background-size:cover; background:url('<?php echo $imageURL[guid]; ?>') no-repeat center;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4><?php echo $imageURL[post_excerpt];?></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php $i++; } ?>
</div>
```

And here's a refined version using the php [ternary](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/3/12/4) operator and the shortcut **<?=** instead of **<?php echo**:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <?php $i=0; foreach ($attachments as $imageURL) { ?>
  <div class="item <?= ($i == 0 ? 'active' : '') ?>" style="background-size:cover; background:url('<?= $imageURL[guid] ?>') no-repeat center;">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h4><?= $imageURL[post_excerpt] ?></h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php $i++; } ?>
</div>
```